# How to change css while scrolling in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i decided to learn Vue.js on a project and i can't get how i can track window scroll and dynamicly change CSS after some distance similar, like i did it with JQuery:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
      if($(window).scrollTop() >= 100) {
        $('header').addClass('fixed');
      } else {
        $('header').removeClass('fixed');
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [Custom Directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/creating-custom-scroll-directives.html) and bind it to any component or element in your Vue instance.

So say you have a `<div>` and name your directive `on-scroll` you would update your `div`: `<div on-scroll="handleScroll">` where `handleScroll` is the method in your Vue instance that is going to, well, handle the scroll event.

Directive:

```
Vue.directive('on-scroll', {
  inserted: function (el, binding) {
    let f = function (evt) {
      if (binding.value(evt, el)) {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', f)
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener('scroll', f)
  }
})
```

Vue Instance:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#el',
  methods: {
    handleScroll: (event, el) => {
       if ( window.scrollY >= 300 ) {
          el.classList.add('fixed');
       } else {
          el.classList.remove('fixed');
       }
    }
  }
});
```