# change background-color of navbar when scroll event with vuejs

Tags: vue.js, background-color

how can I change background-color of navbar when scrolling event with Vuejs. I tried V-scroll event by using this answer [How to change css while scrolling in Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53103899/how-to-change-css-while-scrolling-in-vue)
 this is the code but it does not work?

```
<nav v-scroll="handleScroll">
        <div class="logo">
          <img src="../assets/images/logo.png" alt="logo" />
          <button id="mobBtn" @click="displayList">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
          </button>
        </div>

        <ul class="navlist" id="mobList">
          <li>
            <a href>Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href>About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href>Blog</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href>Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
<script>
export default {
  name: "Header",
  data: {},
  methods: {
  handleScroll: function (evt, el) {
    alert("Dddd")
      if (window.scrollY > 50) {
        el.setAttribute(
          'style',
          'background-color: red;'
        )
      }
      return window.scrollY > 100
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41095814/vuejs-how-to-dynamically-change-a-css-class-after-a-scroll-position/41097438 answer's your question ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add event listener to your window and assign new data to your data model and update it's value when scroll event is started. see code below

**date model**

```
data: {
    scrollPosition: null
},
```

**methods**

```
methods: {
    updateScroll() {
       this.scrollPosition = window.scrollY
    }
}
```

**mounted hook**

```
mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.updateScroll);
}
```

Now in your case, put this in your navbar

```
<nav :class="{change_color: scrollPosition > 50}">
      ...
      ...
</nav>
```

and put css to your change_color class

```
<style scoped>
   .change_color {
       background-color:red
   }
</style
```

Comment: This worked outstandingly for changing the Vuetify (v-app-bar) from one color to another on scroll.  Thank you very much!!  
I did however use a computed property to update the 'color' prop for that component:
appBarColor() {
      return this.scrollPosition > 10 ? 'rgba(255,255,255,1)' : 'rgba(255,255,255,.5)';
    }

This effectively changes the app bar color from translucent to solid white as the page is scrolled.  Super cool!